# Force AssertJ to treat classes as objects rather than Iterables

Tags: java, apache-poi, assertj

I'm trying to use isEqualToComparingFieldByFieldRecursively from [AssertJ](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-features-highlight.html) to compare [HSSFWorkbook](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.html)s from Apache POI

However when I try to use it with a HSSFWorkbook it does not work:

```
    HSSFWorkbook wb1 = new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFWorkbook wb2 = new HSSFWorkbook();

    assertThat(wb1).isEqualToComparingFieldByFieldRecursively(wb2);
```

I am not able to use the isEqualToComparingFieldByFieldRecursively method:
[image]

It looks like since HSSFWorkbook implements Iterable assertThat(wb1) returns a IterableAssert which does not have isEqualToComparingFieldByFieldRecursively like *ObjectAssert* does.

If I cast the HSSFWorkbook to Object that it will act the correct way but the same problem occurs for the other Apache POI classes (HSSFSheet and HSSFRow). What is the cleanest way to force AssertJ to only use ObjectAssert?

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to [`usingRecursiveFieldByFieldElementComparator`](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core-8/api/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#usingRecursiveFieldByFieldElementComparator--), it should be available as `HSSFWorkbook` is an `Iterable`.

If it does not work, can you add a comment to https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core/issues/1002 to get support for your use case in the upcoming recursive comparison api for AssertJ.